# Solving Functional Derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, distribution-theory, greens-function

Define the operator $F$ taking functions $f$ on $(0,\infty)^2$ into $(0,\infty)$ and returning the function $F(f)$ on $(0,\infty)^2$ defiend by
$$
F(f)\triangleq \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t }
}{
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2 }
}
\right)
.  
$$

Then how $F^{-1}$ be represented as an integral operator?  I've been reading a bit on Green's functions $G$ and I'm guessing that
$$
F^{-1}(u)(x) = \sqrt{x}
\int_0^TG(t,x)u(x)dx
,
$$
where $G$ is some nice Green's function.

Is my intuition on the right track?  If so how can I explicitly find the Green's function and so $F^{-1}$?

Comment: It was a typo (I edited it), also f is always positive (actually I forgot to mention this is built into the problem I'm working on)

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, I tweaked the question into a form which is still usable for me.  It looks all good now.

Comment: Oh they were supposed to read $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$etc.. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Notice that the solution for $F^{-1}$ that you propose is linear in $u$, but $F$ is a nonlinear function of $f$ so they cannot be inverse of each other.

Comment: True, so how would I go about finding $F^{-1}$ then?

Comment: Let us take $f(t,x) = g(x)$. In this case $F[f]\equiv 0$, hence you can not find the inverse. Also, you can't really define $F$ on a function $f(t,x)$ with $\partial_x^2 f =0$ (everywhere or for some points).